# How to remove "Submitted by .... on Fri, 06/19/2015 - 22:04" from published content in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes

How to remove "Submitted by .... on Fri, 06/19/2015 - 22:04" from published content in Drupal 7? Where and what parameters and permissions to change? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it by doing below steps.

1. Go to content type edit page i.e. **/admin/structure/types/manage/page**
2. Now under **Display Settings**, uncheck the option **Display author and date information.**

[image]

Comment: **He's asking about doing it in comments** not node. (see question tags)

Comment: But in question he asked about published content not comment, and the message he wanted to remove is not related to comment.

Comment: I am pretty sure  `"Submitted by .... on Fri, 06/19/2015 - 22:04"` shows up in comments as well.

Comment: Let @VassiaAlk clarify our doubt about content or comment part.

Comment: Comments aren't mentioned in the post, except for a tag, "published content" specifically is - I've removed the comment tag since that makes most sense

Comment: Thanku so much @Clive for correcting the things and clarifying doubts.